# SonicWall Global VPN worked on Windows Server 2016 and not working on Windows 10

Tags: vpn, windows-10, windows-server

I have got a weird issue that when I tried to connect to my client VPN
it's connected on the two OSs (Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10) 
but I could not access any of my client's resources (Machines, Databases, ...) while am on Windows 10 and it worked fine and smoothly while am on the windows server.

I used the SonicWall Global VPN client I tried latest and old versions and all of them had the same issue on Windows 10.

Comment: This is a support question specific for a commercial product. Please contact the support of the vendor instead, i.e. it is off-topic here.

Comment: Oh sorry, i think it may something that already known about how windows server interacts with VPN clients and may be different from Windows 10 and I need to enable or disable something. Thanks :)